# GitLab API 401 Error on get request, but not with curl command

Tags: axios, get, gitlab, frontend, gitlab-api

I am trying to get a file from a gitlab project, and I have successfully done this with the following command:

(Apologies for the anonymity)

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>" "https://gitlab.companyname.ag/api/v4/projects/projectid/repository/files/<folder>%2f<folder>%2F<folder>%2F<filename>/raw?ref=master"
```

This returns the data I want correctly.

However, when trying use this in my NextJS application with Axios, I get a 401 Error. Here is my code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import protobuf from "protobufjs";

async function loadProtoFile() {
  const token = process.env.SERVICES_REPO_ACCESS_TOKEN as string;
  const projectId = "1"; //
  const branch = "master";
  const filePath = "path/to/file/example.proto";

  const apiUrl = `https://gitlab.<companyname>.ag/api/v4/projects/${projectId}/repository/files/${encodeURIComponent(
    filePath
  )}/raw?ref=${branch}`;

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(apiUrl, {
      headers: {
        "PRIVATE-TOKEN": token,
      },
    });

    return response.data;
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error(`Failed to fetch file content: ${error.message}`);
  }
}
```

This code throws the error, and it is a 401 error. The url I input is the exact same, I don't know what to do, and can't find any information on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with axios, so I just tried working with fetch instead of axios.
This actually worked:

```js
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
};

async function logGitResponse() {
    const response = await fetch(gitURL, config);
    const value = await response.json();
    console.log(value);
}
```